Vb.net submit data Data to Google Form
I' trying to submit data from VB.NET TO GOOGLE FORM BY CLICKING A BUTTON HERE IS MY GOOGLE FORM FRONT END
GOOGLE FORM FRONT END
AND HERE IS THE SOURCE CODE OF THIS TWO TEXTBOX
SOURCE CODE OF THE TWO TEXTBOX ABOVE
AND MY VB.NET CODE IS LIKE THIS
 Await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByName('entry.1166974658')[0].value='Christian'")

 Await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByName('entry.2005620554')[0].value='Joshua'")

 Await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementsByClassName('NPEfkd RveJvd snByac')[0].click()")

So, what I'm trying to do here is to submit a data to my google form by clicking a single button but the problem is the value 'Christian' and  'Joshua' is not passing to the google form the only thing works is clicking the button
I already try using querySelector like this
  Await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[name='entry.1166974658']');")
  Await WebView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.querySelector('[name='entry.2005620554']');")

but it does not work to. Has anyone encounter this problem before? Can anyone point me to right direction I already try Google and Youtube
